# how to iterate through two lists in python and match up corresponding items

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
nums = [41.25, 38.75, 43.25, 37.25, 37.5, 43.75]
sats = [G01, G03, G04, G11, G28, G32]
```

note: the first item in nums corresponds to first item in sats, the second item in nums corresponds to the second item in sats etc..

I want to loop through nums and where the value is less than 39.00, I want to get its corresponding item from sats?

can anyone help?

Comment: `[sat for num, sat in zip(nums, sats) if num < 39.0]`

Answer (score 1):

```
for num,sat in zip(nums, sats):
    if num<39:
        # do stuff
```

Comment: thanks, that's more simple than I thought